# Working of Count/Badges in Android?

Tags: android

I want to know how does notification read and unread functionality works in android. I want to know how the badges number count is set visible and invisible on read and unread message method.

When I create notification in my application then it will create successfully and add with +1 increment on badges. But after read this notification all other unread notification will also disappear. I want only the reeded message notification/count will be disappeared not for all.all other those are not open will be remain unread on badge. how could I did this.

same like as our message box functionality.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to know how the badges number count is set visible and
>   invisible on read and unread message method

No there is no any direct method to do this. but i show you one way how to achieve this. This solution only working in `SAMSUNG` Devices. There is no guaranty it's working on all devices.

https://github.com/eldhosembabu/mathokkil/

also another way is you can achieve this by **App Widget Provider** in `Android`. for more information go to [AndroidWidgets](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidWidgets/article.html)

Comment: I have created the badges successfully on advertisement page. now I want when the advertisement notification come to user and user read the notification then the badges count is decreased like badges display 5 message unread and user read 2 message then the remaining 3 will be display as unread same like our inbox message

Comment: @user3736827 how to created? as per my link.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put it on Launcher Icon , then in android its not by default functionality given. The reason behind it is, when apk is generated, apk will not find that icon attached with it, so that is the main reason.

Alternate is, you can create widget for it. Creating widget is only solution to achieve this.